# How to change bars colors with scale_fill_manual() in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my bars to correspond to a legend and to have them colored with my own color, not the default one.

```
# library
library(ggplot2)

# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("IFNg_WNH", 2) , 
            rep("IFNg_AA", 2), 
            rep("IL1b_WNH", 2), 
            rep("IL1b_AA", 2),
            rep("IL6_WNH", 2), 
            rep("IL6_AA", 2) 
)


condition <- rep(c("down", "up"), 6)

value <- c(452,216,
           348,327,
           207,61,
           75,53,
           177,191,
           379,318)
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)

data

# Grouped
p <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")


z <- p+labs(y = "Number of genes", x = "Cytokines")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(axis.line=element_line(size=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c('up', 'down'))

z
```

Once I add

```
z + scale_fill_manual(values=c('#eb4034','#0a0a0a'))
```

The color is changing but the legend reverts to the wrong one. What is happening?

Comment: What is your goal with `labels = c("up", "down")`? Are you trying to change the order in which the values appear in the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `type` to `scale_fill_discrete`

> type: One of the following:
>
> • A character vector of color codes.
>
> • A list of character vectors of color codes.
>
> • A function that returns a discrete colour/fill scale

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  labs(y = "Number of genes", x = "Cytokines") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA)) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c('up', 'down'), type=c('#eb4034','#0a0a0a'))
```

[image: bar plot]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here. First, `scale_fill_manual()` essentially “overwrites” `scale_fill_discrete()`. Instead, use just one `scale_fill_*()` call including all relevant arguments:

```
library(ggplot2)

p + 
  labs(y = "Number of genes", x = "Cytokines")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(axis.line=element_line(size=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))+
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c('up', 'down'), values=c('#eb4034', '#0a0a0a'))
```

[image]

However - currently, the `labels` argument is in effect recoding your data, so that `"up"` values are labeled `"down"` and vice versa, which I assume isn’t what you want. My best guess is you’re actually trying to change the order the labels appear in the legend. If so, you can change the factor levels of `condition` to the order you want:

```
data$condition <- factor(data$condition, c("up", "down"))

p <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")

p + 
  labs(y = "Number of genes", x = "Cytokines")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(axis.line=element_line(size=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#eb4034', '#0a0a0a'))
```

[image]